# Why fileNameSet is null?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, java-7, talend

I am new to Talend and I am creating a bean, to aggregate Four messages to One . I am using cFile componnent which consume 4 files from the directory, followed by aggregrator and then processor. The code for the aggregated Bean is as follow:

```
package beans;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class AggregateBody implements AggregationStrategy{

public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldEx, Exchange newEx) {
    Set<String> fileNameSet =  new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> bodySet =  new HashSet<String>();
    if(oldEx==null){
        fileNameSet.add((String) newEx.getIn().getHeader("fileName"));
        bodySet.add(newEx.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        newEx.setProperty("fileName",fileNameSet);
        System.out.println(fileNameSet);

        newEx.setProperty("body",bodySet);
        System.out.println(bodySet);
        return newEx;
    }

    oldEx.getProperty("fileName",fileNameSet);
    fileNameSet.add((String) oldEx.getIn().getHeader("fileName"));
    oldEx.setProperty("fileName",fileNameSet);
    System.out.println(fileNameSet);

    oldEx.getProperty("body",bodySet);
    bodySet.add(oldEx.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    oldEx.setProperty("body",bodySet);
    return oldEx;
}
```

}

So I am not getting reason why the sysout for fileName is [null].

Comment: I have never used Talend, but in Apache Camel it is header `CamelFileName`, not `fileName`. `newEx.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName")`

Comment: @Bedla Got it Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting null filename is , the [filenameset](/questions/tagged/filenameset) was not updating. The code should be like this:

```
package beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;

public class AggregateBody implements AggregationStrategy {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldEx, Exchange newEx) {
    List<String> fileNameSet = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> bodySet = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (oldEx == null) {
        fileNameSet.add((String) newEx.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
        newEx.setProperty("CamelFileName", fileNameSet);
        bodySet.add(newEx.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        newEx.setProperty("body", bodySet);
        return newEx;
    }

    fileNameSet = (List<String>) oldEx.getProperty("CamelFileName", fileNameSet);
    bodySet = (List<String>) oldEx.getProperty("body", bodySet);

    fileNameSet.add((String) newEx.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));

    bodySet.add(newEx.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    oldEx.setProperty("CamelFileName", fileNameSet);
    oldEx.setProperty("body", bodySet);
    return oldEx;
}
```

}